# TypeError when Assigning Slice: "can only assign an iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I'm writing recursive code to reverse a list in-place. This is what I have, but the code fails at assigning the slice to the input list, giving the error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`:

```
def reverse(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return

    temp = a[0]
    a[0] = a[-1]
    a[-1] = temp
    a[1:-1] = reverse(a[1:-1])
    return a
```

I have read that slices are not objects, so I attempted to use `list()` and `range()` to convert the returned slice, but by doing that, I still get the same error. Is there a way of assigning a slice to another slice of an array?

Comment: your problem is `return` which send `None` - you need `return a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your problem is `return` which sends `None` and gives `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

You need `return a`. And rest of code start working.

**BTW:** You could use `<= 1` instead of `== 1` to work with empty list too.

```
def reverse(a):
    if len(a) <= 1: # <-- `<=` to work with empty list
        return a    # <-- has to return `a`

    temp = a[0]
    a[0] = a[-1]
    a[-1] = temp
    #a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]

    a[1:-1] = reverse(a[1:-1])

    return a

# --- tests ---

print(reverse([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(reverse([1]))
print(reverse([]))
```

---

**EDIT:** To replace elements you can also use

```
a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]
```

---

**EDIT:** Using slice to create list with single element and `list + list` to join lists you can do:

```
def reverse(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a

    return a[-1:] + reverse(a[1:-1]) + a[:1]
```

---

**EDIT:** You can even write it as `lambda` function (if you like [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) which often uses recursion)

```
reverse = lambda a: a if len(a) <= 1 else a[-1:] + reverse(a[1:-1]) + a[:1]

# --- tests ---

print(reverse([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(reverse([1,2,3,4]))
print(reverse([1]))
print(reverse([]))
```

Comment: I added `a[0], a[-1] = a[-1], a[0]`

Comment: I added `a[-1:] + reverse(a[1:-1]) + a[:1]`

Comment: I added `lambda` function - if you like `functional programming` which often uses recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe this algorithm would be a bit closer to what you have in mind:

- Here we are passing an index to the function you've already designed.
- We would then increment that index using (`-~index` or simply `index + 1`).

```
def reverse(a, index=0):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return []
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a
    if index == len(a) - 1:
        return a

    temp = a[0]
    a[0] = a[-1]
    a[-1] = temp
    return reverse(a, index + 1)


print(reverse([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
print(reverse([100, 90, -10, 1200, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

---

The three statements that you already have in your code are much more "algorithmic" (in all languages) than using Python's swap (`a, b = b, a`):

```
temp = a[0]
a[0] = a[-1]
a[-1] = temp
```

#### Output

```
[9, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
[9, 90, -10, 1200, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse in-place

We will just keep on swapping start and end of list till both of them meet

```
def reverse(a,start=0,end=len(a)-1):
    if start==end:return
    a[start],a[end] = a[end],a[start]
    reverse(a,start+1,end-1)
    # return a # if it is inplace no need to return
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
reverse(a)
print(a)
```

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```